# docker-compose with explicit file option and exec problem

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have some services defined in a custom docker-compose yaml file.

```
version: "3.7"

services:

 proxy:
    container_name: nginx
    hostname:       nginx
 …

 database:
   container_name: postgresql
   hostname:       PostgreSQL
 …

 backendservice:
   container_name: backendservice
   hostname:       backendservice
 …

 angular:
   container_name: angular
   hostname:       angular
 …
```

I can see the services running using `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml ps`
when I try `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml exec <service name> bash` or `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml backendservice bash` I get,

**`ERROR: No such service: backendservice`**

What is the correct way to call ?

Comment: It is `docker-compose -f <compose_file> <command> <service_name> <args>`, e.g. `docker-compose -f compose.yml exec myservice bash`. You should check the name for your service. You might have a typo. The only way to get `no such service` is to mistype the name.

Comment: @StefanGolubović The spelling is same. I guess it is the problem with different logged in users running the command. I am not sure. I haven't read about it before.